# Hover not working in the chrome, but working with IE, safari, firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I am new to CSS I was trying to learn how to create a menu using CSS. I created it but found a issue. It is working fine in other browsers but not in chrome. I did not get what is the issue.

Following is the style sheet used in this menu.

```
#main
{width: 150px;}

#main ul,
#main li,
#main a,
{

  padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
margin: 0px;

}

#main ul,#main li
{
 list-style-type: none;
}

ul#main li > a
{
display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    padding-left:10px;
    text-align: left;
align: center;
    height: 32px;

    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: bold 12px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#main > li
{
  padding:0px 0px 5px 5px;
  background-color: #E44d2e;
 align:center;
border-bottom: solid 1px;

}



 ul#submenu
{
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
float: right;
border-bottom: solid 1px;
 border: 0px;
height: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
display:none;

}

ul#main li:hover
{
height: 40px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
width: 150px;
display:block;
  background-color:#ec633f;

border-bottom: solid 1px;
text-align:center;



}

ul#main li:hover > ul#submenu
{
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
float: none;
top: -32px;
left: 150px;
margin: 0px;
height: auto;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
display:block;
  background-color: #f9e5cc;
color: black;



}

ul#submenu li:hover
{

z-index: 10;
  float: none;
 margin: 0px;
 height: auto;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
display:block;
 background-color: #f3d8bd;

}


ul#submenu li > a
{ 
color: black;
}
</style>
```

Following is the code used too create the html menu

```
<ul id="main">
<li > <a href="#">Google</a><ul id="submenu"><li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li></ul></li>
<li id="submenu"><a href="#"> Microsoft</a><ul id="submenu"><li ><a href="#" >Test 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li></ul></li>
<li > <a href="#">Apple</a><ul id="submenu"><li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li></ul></li>
<li > <a href="#">IBM</a><ul id="submenu"><li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li></li></ul></li>
</ul>
```

The above code's working example is present on : [Working code]http://techisquest.blogspot.in/2013/04/simple-css-menu.html

Comment: You can't have the same ID for two elements, e.g. (`<ul id="submenu">` and `<li id="submenu">`)

Comment: You said you "found an issue" but you haven't told us what exactly that issue is...

Comment: I would rephrase the sentence "I created it but found a issue" I created it but facing a issue. I tried a different style but still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much of the R and D I found the issue. The following selectors used in the CSS were wrong :

```
ul#submenu li:hover


ul#submenu li > a
```

These should have been like

```
ul#main  li ul#submenu li:hover

and 

ul#main  li ul#submenu li a:hover
```

The above change resolved my issue.